# Find out where a thread has been blocked

Tags: java, multithreading

In java, i have 2 threads started at the same time. However, i noticed the thread 2 is being blocked but i do not know where. Is there a way in java to find out where a thread has been blocked/waiting? thank u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`jstack`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html) to get the stack traces for all threads. That'll tell you where exactly in the code your thread is blocked.

To get a more detailed picture of what's happening inside your process, you could use [`VisualVM`](http://visualvm.java.net/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `isAlive()` method to verify if the thread is still active or not. Here's a sample code to check all the threads in your memory:

```
public class ThreadStates{
 public static void main(String[] args){
  Thread t = new Thread();
  Thread.State e = t.getState(); 
  Thread.State[] ts = e.values(); 
  for(int i = 0; i < ts.length; i++){
   System.out.println(ts[i]); 
  }   
 }
}
```

Comment: This is useful to know if my thread is still alive, however i wish to know where in my code the thread is waiting...as it is not running as expected

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jstack` to find where a thread is blocked. However if you want to check a thread within the same program you can using thread.getStackTrace()